# Windows 2000 and .Net 2.0+

Tags: .net

I have heard, that Windows 2000 can only be used together with .Net 2.0 and no other version above this. Is that true and if it is, do you have an official Post or something like that from Microsoft, where I can read about the restriction?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to [.NET Framework System Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww.aspx), you can select the version you want from the dropdown.

Yes, `Windows 2000 Professional with SP4` is listed as being compatible with FW 2.0, but not above.

Comment: I already visited this page, but I cant choose the .Net 2.0 directly... there is only 1.1, 3.5, 4, 4.5

Comment: @Daffi Choose 4 and you will get the big table. Alternatively, choose 3.5 and you will find Windows 2000 in the list of unsupported systems.

Answer (score 2):

The supported operating systems for later versions of the .NET Framework do not include Windows 2000. The direct successor to V2.0 was V3, which supports the operating systems listed on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232852c5-9dbe-415a-a49a-1c4f1bf6fcdb%28v=vs.90%29).